# Defining an array Constants using the const keyword with php version 5.3

Tags: php

Works as of PHP 5.6.0 or newer

```
const ANIMALS = array('dog', 'cat', 'bird');
echo ANIMALS[1]; // outputs "cat"
```

How to Defining an array Constants using the const keyword with php version 5.3?

Comment: Do you have to use PHP5.3? It has a very long beard now

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer to the question is **You cannot do that in PHP5.3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid the answer is that until PHP5.6.0 you could not do this.

> From the manual
>
> Constants may only evaluate to scalar values. As of PHP 5.6 it is possible to define array constant using const keywords

PHP5.3 is very old now and was posted as End-Of-Life on 14 Aug 2014